# Using generic packages with protected type in Modelsim 10.xy

Tags: vhdl, modelsim

I am trying to use generic packages with a protected type in Modelsim 10.0a. The technote vhdl2008.note states:

> - a basic generic package and its instantiation with some noteworthy 
>     restrictions:
>
>   1. generic lists on package can contain constant generics and package 
>        generics
>   2. the generic package can be instantiated as a design unit, but not in 
>        any local declarative region.
>   3. Generics cannot depend on other generics in the same generic list
>
>   It is reasonable to use this to instantiate the generic fixed and float
>     packages from IEEE.  You can write your own generic package, instantiate it, 
>     and use it.  Just keep within the restrictions.

Now I have a generic package `test_generic_pkg.vhd`:

```vhdl
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

package test_generic_pkg is
    generic(
        WIDTH : natural := 16
    );

    type test_type is protected
        procedure set(d : std_logic_vector(WIDTH-1 downto 0));
        impure function get return std_logic_vector;
    end protected;
end package test_generic_pkg;

package body test_generic_pkg is
    type test_type is protected body
        variable data : std_logic_vector(WIDTH-1 downto 0);

        procedure set(d : std_logic_vector(WIDTH-1 downto 0)) is
        begin
            data := d;
        end procedure set;

        impure function get return std_logic_vector is
        begin
            return data;
        end function get;
    end protected body;
end package body test_generic_pkg;
```

An used by an entity/architecture `tb.vhd`:

```vhdl
package test_pkg is new work.test_generic_pkg generic map( WIDTH => 16 );

library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;

use work.test_pkg.all;

entity tb is
end entity tb;

architecture behavioural of tb is
    shared variable test : test_type;
    signal clk : std_logic := '0';
begin

    clk_gen: process is
    begin
        wait for 50 ns;
        clk <= not clk;
    end process;

    test1_p: process(clk) is
        variable cnt : unsigned(15 downto 0) := to_unsigned(0, 16);
    begin
        if rising_edge(clk) then
            test.set(std_logic_vector(cnt));
            cnt := cnt + 1;
        end if;
    end process;

    test2_p: process(clk) is
    begin
        if falling_edge(clk) then
            assert false report to_string(test.get) severity note;
        end if;
    end process;

end architecture behavioural;
```

This two files can be tested with the `sim.do` file:

```
vlib work
vcom -work work -2008 -novopt test_generic_pkg.vhd tb.vhd
vsim -novopt work.tb
```

When executing this do file Modelsim compiles both files and while loading the libraries for the simulation it fails with:

```
...
# Loading work.queue_pkg(body)
# Loading work.queue64
...
# ** INTERNAL ERROR: pkgref: export lookup failed for package #0
# Error loading design
```

I also tried to put the package instantiation in a separate file but the results stays the same. What is the solution to get generic packages with protected type working with Modelsim? Using generic packages works fine without a protected type and protected types in a normal package also.

P.S.: Modelsim 10.0a seems to not support this feature although it is not mentioned in the technote. What version of Modelsim added this feature?

Answer (score 2):

With the help of a nice guy from the Mentor Graphics Forums we found out that it is not supported by this Modelsim version.

The results for different Modelsim versions are:

- Modelsim 10.0a: Does not work
- Modelsim 10.0f: Does not work
- Modelsim 10.3a: Does work